# Assembly: comment character ; positioning

Tags: assembly, conventions, comments

I am trying to learn Assembly, and, as for now, I only barely got started. I don't know much of the style conventions, since I haven't really looked into it yet.
I know comments begin with a semicolon, since the end of an instruction is marked with an end-of-line character (**\n**); most of the code examples I've seen separate with blank characters the semicolon *and* the comment from the instruction, as anyone would expect.

```
global some_rnd_labl

section .data
   hifive   dd   0x00000005

section .text
some_rnd_labl:
   mov    eax, [esp+4]     ; Adds the second last item in the stack...
   add    eax, [esp+8]     ;  and then the third last one.
    add   eax, [hifive]    ; Good job, accumulator! Hi-5!
   mov    edx, eax         ; Now store the result in dx...
   ret
```

**However**,
would it *universally* be considered bad practice to write the semicolon immediately next to the instruction, and only then put the blank characters, or is it just a matter of taste / *subjective opinion*?

```
...
mov    eax, [esp+4];        Adds the second last item in the stack...
 add    eax, [esp+8];       and then the third last one.
 add   eax, [hifive];       Good job, accumulator! Hi-5!
mov    edx, eax;            Now store the result in dx...
...
```

The reason I'm asking this seemingly (and likely) self-answering question is the way I'm acquainted with C++ and Java, both of which end instructions with semicolons and mark inline comments with "**//**", and separating the comment marker from the comment itself could be unintuitive and/or misleading; I think that style is easier to read, but I'm not sure that the average programmer wouldn't find it less readable just because it is unusual.
EG, you could see:

```
; Assembly code for my compiler / OS / CPU

mov    eax, [esp+4];          Adds the second last item in the stack...
```

as it's C++ ~counterpart:

```
// C++ based pseudocode
//  (notice how the semicolon and "//" are mashed together)

std::vector<int> stack(DEFINED_ELSEWHERE);
int
 var1 = stackArray[1];//   Adds the second last item in the stack...
```

Yes, I realize this is a silly (and apparently non-objective) question, but I think it is still worth asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm voting to close this as opinion based... that said, my personal opinion is, that semicolon right after instruction is bad, because it looks like part of instruction, but it is not. Also in C/C++/Java the semicolon is statement separator, allowing you to use multiple statements on single line, while in asm the end-of-line-comment doesn't work like that of course. Overall trying to make the asm look similar to C syntax will probably backfire later, when some similar C syntax works completely different. I suggest to learn it as different language, with different syntax.

Comment: My opinion is - I prefer the `;` next to the comment itself. I find if the semicolon is not easily identifiable that my eyes are forced to search for the semicolon to confirm that what I am looking at is in fact a comment.

Comment: Agree with both, similarly in C I don't put the `//` immediately after the code statement and then a large gap (as in the last example): I line them up vertically where possible, with the `//` visually part of the comment and not part of the code.

Comment: It is not a silly question: some might find the presentation to be a waste of time when they just want to get the assignment finished. But style in presentation goes side by side with style of coding itself. And apart from making the code more readable when you come back to it later, formatting nicely is no waste of time: it allows another part of the brain to review the code just written, or to consider the code to be written next.

Comment: After you have written some more assembly code, you will no longer write comments on every single line, like `Now store the result in dx...`. Just like you don't write `a = 1;   // set a to 1` in C or Java. And then the semicolons will be wasted. And it looks totally ugly too!

Comment: Indeed comments are not there to repeat what the language man pages say, but to clarify the intentions of what the code is achieving.

Comment: This is opinion based... but yes, that would be horrendously offensive to assembly programmers.

Comment: Is it unusual? Yes. Would it work? Yes. Should you do it? No, probably not. Whenever you learn *any* new language, you find that the syntax is unusual and that you are uncomfortable with it. But eventually, after using it enough, you will grow comfortable with it, and thus be able to read others' code more easily, too. Thus, you should not cripple yourself by adopting an unusual style. You should force yourself to become more comfortable with the standard syntax. It won't take long as you think to get comfortable!

Comment: __1:__   I find it highly illogical to see more separation between the mnemonic and its operand(s) (2 things that belong to each other) than between the operand(s) and the semicolon (2 things that have nothing to do with each other). __2:__   What's  also very disturbing on reading assembly source is a failing vertical alignment. Put the mnemonics nicely above each other, same for the operands, same for the comments. __3:__   Still a good question though!